# how to delete a file in pg admin 4 web query tool

Tags: file, pgadmin-4

I'm working in pgAdmin 4 webtool.

When using the query tool, I can save and open files, but I can't delete them.

I'm saving the files using the following method:

[image: here is how to save files]

But then there is no way to delete saved queries that I don't need anymore.

Here is the file manager:

[image: here is the file manager]

Did I overlook it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If not through File Manager, then how? There must be some way to do some cleaning up.

Answer (score 0):

As pgAdmin4 can be used as web application & hosted on web servers that functionality is not provided in File manager.

Comment: Is there any way to delete those files?

Comment: Not from pgAdmin4, You can manually goto pgAdmin4 data folder and delete from there, there is a feature request open for the same https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/4607